# Cocos2D Moving sprite sometimes jerky

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Here I want to move some cocos2D sprite object from top to bottom. Sprites r generated at random position in screen. Some time all sprite's movement s jerky..I can't use CCMove as I want to maintain equal distance between sprite.

```
[self schedule: @selector(updateObjects:)];


-(void)updateObjects:(ccTime) dt
{
    //when I print dt, it gives different value..
    //jerk comes when this value s larger than ideal value..


    for(Obstacles *Obs in ObsArray)
    {
        CGPoint pos = Obs.position;
        pos.y -= gameSpeed;
        Obs.position = pos;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: jerky means just stays all sprites 1 or 2 seconds in screen n then continues. If it is problem with fps then how can I fix this sir?

Comment: You should find out why you get high delta times. I'm guessing things like creating sprites on the fly, or playing an unbuffered audio. Anything that loads a resource into memory.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, ok thanks for the reply sir. Will try for reducing some file access latency. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem by 
1. Removed all printf and cocos2D logs
2. Added separate thread for image loading.
3. Used multiple 1024x1024 sprite sheet in place of 2048x2048 in HD mode.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d uses variable time step: `dt` is time in seconds *since last call* of this scheduled selector. If your `gameSpeed` is distance the object has to move by per second (in points), then you must change your object position by `gameSpeed * dt`.

Comment: that will only make the animation "jerkier" because now the objects move a greater distance if delta is suddenly inexplicably high. This results in big jumps in position.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, yes. This solution not fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i tried lots of thing, at the end i found that it will jerk more on android devices then ios devices.. the frame-rate they rendered should be updated on constant interval .. if you use update method then set the constant delta time

For example i have used update method

```
void MyClass::update(float dt) {
    int positioniteration=8;
    int valocityiteration=8;
    world->Step(1/60.0,valocityiteration,positioniteration);//60 FPS }
```

and also i have added these lines in appdelegate

```
director->setDepthTest(false);
director->setProjection(Director::Projection::_2D);// MY GAME IS 2D SO USED 2D PROJECTION .. IT HELPED ME
```

Hope this helps.:)